# syntax validator for a less file

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, less, antlr

I need a validator for a less file. I need to validate a single less file, at only syntax level.

I can't get the validator to follow the dependencies or detect if a mixin is declared or not. That is my real problem.

I have found a lot of less processors which fail because the file has dependencies that i can't provide in this point of the process.

npm package would be perfect.

Comment: I can assure you that no such tool exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I decided to use [antlr4](http://www.antlr.org/)

Steps:

- install antlr in the computer or add to the deployment process
- get the grammar for your language (less is already done)
- get the npm package to process the grammar
- Use it in your app

The configuration is:

```
$ cd /usr/local/lib
$ sudo curl -O http://www.antlr.org/download/antlr-4.5-complete.jar
$ export CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.5-complete.jar:$CLASSPATH"
$ alias antlr4='java -jar /usr/local/lib/antlr-4.5-complete.jar'
$ alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig
```

This info is directly from the web page.

Now you can get the grammar from https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4

At this point you can [generate the javascript version of your grammar](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR4/JavaScript+Target)

In my case, I created a directory, I downloaded the files and coded all my tests inside:

```
antlr4 -Dlanguage=JavaScript LessParser.g4
antlr4 -Dlanguage=JavaScript LessLexer.g4
```

This process generates a javascript file that you will use, but you need the antlr lib for use this files in your node program.

```
npm link antlr4
```

Ant now starts to code:

```
var antlr4 = require('antlr4/index');
var MyGrammarLexer = require('./LessLexer.js');
var MyGrammarParser = require('./LessParser.js');
var input = "html{ .hey(); color: @light-blue; background:#333}";
var chars = new antlr4.InputStream(input);
var lexer = new MyGrammarLexer.LessLexer(chars);
var tokens  = new antlr4.CommonTokenStream(lexer);
var parser = new MyGrammarParser.LessParser(tokens);
parser.buildParseTrees = true;


var ErrorListener = antlr4.error.ErrorListener;
function CustomErrorListener() {
   ErrorListener.call(this);
   return this;
}

CustomErrorListener.prototype = Object.create(ErrorListener.prototype);
CustomErrorListener.prototype.constructor = CustomErrorListener;
CustomErrorListener.prototype.syntaxError = function(recognizer, offendingSymbol, line, column, msg, e) {
    throw ('throw a simple exception');
};

parser.addErrorListener(new CustomErrorListener());

try{
  var tree = parser.stylesheet();
} catch (e){
  console.log('I catch you!!!')
}
```

The important parts in this code are the function lessLexer, lessParser, and parser.stylesheet(); This are different per grammar. The last one is difficult to know, but it is the point in the grammar that you want to validate. In my case, I get the file LessParser.g4, and you have the different node in the grammar in the definition:

```
parser grammar LessParser;

options { tokenVocab=LessLexer; }

stylesheet
  : statement*
  ;

statement
  : importDeclaration
  | ruleset
  | variableDeclaration ';'
  | mixinDefinition
  ;

variableName
  : AT variableName
  | AT Identifier
  ;

commandStatement
  : (expression+) mathStatement?
  ;

mathCharacter
  : TIMES | PLUS | DIV | MINUS | PERC
  ;
```

In this case, you can validate the string like a stylesheet, statement, variableName ...

The last interesting point is the Error Validation, I use it to stop the validation in the first error, my case is very simple, but you can improve this point

Comment: How many of [these tests](https://github.com/less/less.js/tree/master/test/less) does this validator pass?

Comment: I don't know, but if you are interested I will lunch this weekend and I will tell you. The important, you can update the grammar if don't suit you.

Comment: No, do not bother to do it for me only (I linked to the test suit only for reference in case if *you* are interested to know how much of Less syntax a syntax parser cover). In fact it does not need to pass all the stuff there, but it's still a lot of specific syntactic constructions, so I'm afraid for a less or more covering validator the grammar will grow quite bloating... Either way maybe you'll be interested to look at [`less4j`](https://github.com/SomMeri/less4j) sources since it's also uses `antlr` (thus also uses related grammar code).